# Angular, implementing Filters with Pagination

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

So I'm playing around with angular and seem to have the gist of filtering, the problem that I have ran into is as follows:

(Thanks to Eric Terpstra for posting this great tutorial!)

Working with this code base as a fun little example: https://github.com/ericterpstra/jsCats/tree/master/ngCats

Live Demo: http://ericterpstra.com/apps/jsCats/ngCats/#/cats/1

I have ran into an issue with filtering so many objects (or possibly I'm just not doing it correctly) if I apply a 'filter:query' to the 'live' demo above. What happens is it ONLY filters the results within the selected 'ng-view' and not the global scope. Now is this something that can't be done by angular, or and I missing a paramater somewhere on how to do this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I suspect your `query` variable is attached to some scope that is getting destroyed upon each change of the partial inside the `ngView`. Can you provide a little more detail on what exactly you changed?